# How to play video of all formats using jquery in web application

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

I have a web application where users upload videos of all formats. I have tried HTML5 video tag, but it plays only mp4 files that only works in chrome. I also tried videojs plugin, it too plays mp4 files. Should I convert videos into mp4 format or is there any jquery video plugin that plays all types of video ?

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert video at server side:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated than just converting, because different browsers need different codecs.  Zencoder has a good guide.

http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/